# Run with stdin in CLion

Tags: c, clion

I would like to ask if there is any possibility to run code with custom parameters in CLion. And where to put the file.txt in project folder.

Something equivalent to `./program <file.txt`

Comment: Please, choose either XCode or CLion, as the answers will be different.

Comment: Are you asking for arguments passed into `argv[]`? Or are you trying to redirect `stdin` to a file?

Comment: @thebusybee I am trying to redirect ```stdin``` to a file.

Answer (score 1):

In CLion, go to your `Run/Debug Configurations`. There's a field named `Program arguments`. This field allows you to set "a custom parameter":

[image: "Run/Debug Configurations" Dialog - CLion 2019.2.2]

You can find the corresponding documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).
An excerpt from the documentation to help finding the correct dialog:

> With the Navigation bar visible (View | Appearance | Navigation Bar), the available run/debug configurations are displayed in the run/debug configuration selector in the Run area:

Note that this of course only works for executable targets (or non executable targets that have an executable set).

Also note that this will most likely not allow you to do any shell redirection. Setting the field to `< myfile.txt` will not have the effects you are looking for. It will literally copy the strings `<` and `myfile.txt` as input arguments 1 and 2 (0 being the binary name).
If you want to pass file contents in this manner you'll have to just pass the file path using this method and then open & load the file in your application.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if redirection of `stdin` for the program to be run or debugged is still not implemented. See the issue ["Add an option to specify default input and output streams for console applications"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3153) at JetBrain's bugtracker.

Other IDEs like Eclipse can do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible.

> In the Run/Debug Configuration, you’ll find a new field called
> Redirect input from. Enable it, and fill in the file path/name:

*Source: https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/03/clion-2020-1-eap-input-redirection-config-macros/#input_redirection*

[image]